# TempVars in Select Case

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to use a `Select Case` to evaluate a `TempVar` string value, but the case is not giving me the correct result.

My VBA Code so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Select Case TempVars!CurrentStatus

        Case Entered
            'code to disable some controls

        Case In Progress
            'code to disable some controls

        Case Ready to Approve
            'code to disable some controls

        Case Approved
            'code to disable some controls

        Case Else
            Call MsgBox("Case statement didn't catch", vbInformation, "Tempvar test for case statements")

    End Select
End Sub
```

The `TempVar` is set as follows in another form:

```
Dim StrUserInput1 As String

TempVars("CurrentStatus").Value = DLookup("Status", "Control", "Status = '" & StrUserInput1 & "'")

'This is set by comparing the user input vs allowed status (for reports which is yet to be implemented)
```

I've tried setting the `Case` as `Case "Entered"` but it always select the first case, not the correct one. If its formatted as show above, the result is `Case Else`

Can anyone offer some insight on why or how I'm not getting the correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised the code even runs and doesn't throw an error.  You need to have the string literals in quotes, like this:

```
Select Case TempVars!CurrentStatus

    Case "Entered"
        code to disable some controls

    Case "In Progress"
        code to disable some controls

    Case "Ready to Approve"
        'code to disable some controls

    Case "Approved"
        'code to disable some controls

    Case Else

        Call MsgBox("Case statement didn't catch", vbInformation, "Tempvar test for case statements")

End Select
```

If that doesn't work, put a breakpoint on `Select Case TempVars!CurrentStatus` to see what the value of `TempVars!CurrentStatus` is when it enters the case expression.

Comment: @SeanCheshire - Yeah, I always assume that `Option Explicit` is being used, and you see where that got me.

Comment: Thanks for the help, need to start using the `Option Explicit` more often :S